# Interact with pc in python (mouse+screenshot)

Tags: python, mouse, opencv, pynput

I'm writing a bot that interact with the pc. Briefly what I do is:

-Take a screenshot of the screen
-recognize an object (with cv2 matchTemplate) on this screenshot
-make some mouse action using the position found (example: move the mouse pointer on an icon found in the previous point)
-restart from the first point

Now, I have to interact with some object in movement on the screen, and so I need a fast way to take screenshot, or an alternative way to do this job, what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the module [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)!

It has screenshot functions:

```py
pyautogui.screenshot('my_screenshot.png')
```

Mouse movement and clicking:

```py
pyautogui.moveTo(100, 200)
pyautogui.click()
```

And basic image location on screen:

```py
button_location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('button.png')
```

So if you wanted to click on a certain image on the screen you could run:

```py
x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('form_button.png') # Gets coords of center of image
pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

As stated on their site:

> On a 1920 x 1080 screen, the locate function calls take about 1 or 2
>   seconds. This may be too slow for action video games, but works for
>   most purposes and applications.

So bear this in mind.